# Specify Office Word application default SharePoint site and disable SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, group-policy

Our organization has Office 2013 applications, and SharePoint 2013 on-premises (which we do use) and Office 365 - SharePoint Online (which we DO NOT use).

Problem is that SharePoint Online is also integrated by default in client Office application (for example. Word or Excel).

I want to remove SharePoint Online from save locations on all computers, and specify only on-premise SharePoint. I believe this can be done using Group policy and ADMX for Office365 but did not find solution (which GPO items should be modified).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue, and not possible to overcome in todays version:

> There are some group policies that control the Backstage area, but they are mostly all or nothing, removing all SharePoint referencing not just the Office 365 ones.
>
> The workaround below should remove the O365 SharePoint on line content from the Office Save As screen and the "SharePoint" link in the contact card.
>
> **Workaround**: None
>
> **Current Status**: This is a known issue, it could be addressed in a future version of Microsoft Office.

Posted by Warren_R_Msft in the blog [Office 2013, Remove unwanted SharePoint Online / SkyDrive "Save As" backstage items](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_integration__sharepoint/archive/2013/11/27/office-2013-remove-unwanted-sharepoint-online-skydrive-quot-save-as-quot-backstage-items.aspx) November 26, 2013.

In Word there are options settings for Save available, but it's an all or nothing option on *Show additional places for saving, even if sign-in may be required*.

[image]

## Workaround

However, there is kind of a workaround posted by *Johnny Zhang MSFT Support* on the topic:

> Based on my test, we can disable SharePoint site save location as below steps:
>
> 1. From Registry Editor, browse to:
>      `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet`
> 2. Create a new DWORD value of UseOnlineContent, Set the value of UseOnlineContent to 1.
> 3. Re-open Office application.

Reference: [How do I globally disable SharePoint?](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/150245.aspx)

It's not a full solution to your problem, but it may give you hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\ServicesManagerCache\Identities\USERNAME@DOMAIN_AD

Remove keys below this root key (user@domain_AD)

Answer (score 0):

You can also navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\ServicesManagerCache\Identities\`
and view all your Sharepoint/Onedrive locations. I was able to remove them from my Office Save As page by setting the values for *ConnectionState* and *EnabledCapabilities* to 0.

NOTE: I've only done this for Sharepoint sites I'm (probably) not ever going to use on this computer anymore, as I'm not certain in which way it could affect your connections/permissions for these sites.